# Why won't the asset pipeline find my JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use a JQuery plugin in a Rails 3.2.8 app.

Relevant code follows...

In the `/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` file:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = javascript_include_tag :defaults
    = javascript_include_tag '/assets/nospam.js'
```

In the `/public/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require nospam
```

In the `/app/assets/javascripts/nospam.js` file:

```
$('#my-email').html(function(){
  var e = "me";
  var a = "@";
  var d = "mysite";
  var c = ".com";
  var h = 'mailto:' + e + a + d + c;
  $(this).parent('a').attr('href', h);
  return e + a + d + c;
});
```

In the `/app/views/layouts/index.html.haml` file:

```
%p
We love email, so why not send a message to
%a{:href => "#"}
  %span#my-email please enable javascript to view
and let us know what's on your mind.
```

In the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

I have run `bundle install` and restarted the server but the plugin isn't working and in Chrome's Javascript console I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/nospam.js 404 (Not Found)
```

In `rails console`, I get:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
 => ["/Users/steven/Dropbox/testivate/app/assets/javascripts", "/Users/steven/Dropbox/testivate/app/assets/stylesheets", "/Users/steven/Dropbox/testivate/vendor/assets/javascripts", "/Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jquery-rails-2.1.3/vendor/assets/javascripts"]
```

I've got this working for now by disabling the assets pipeline but I know I should re-enable it eventually for performance reasons.

What should I do to make it work?

Thanks,

Steven.

Comment: Try to move the jquery-rails of of the :assets group.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I tried that, then bundle install and restarting the server, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's the problem. Please put all your javascripts to app/assets/javascripts/ directory.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I now have nospam.js in /app/assets/javascripts/, /public/javascripts/ and /vendor/assets/javascripts/. I still have the same problem.

Comment: the application.js is also in app/assets/javascripts ?

Comment: It wasn't, but it is now. I restarted the server and the problem remains!

Comment: Why are you listing nospam twice? Once in the application.js and once in the layout? And if you're putting nospam.js in app/assets/javascripts, then the javascript_include_tag should have only the name of the asset, without the path.

Answer (score 3):

Take out the line:

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
= javascript_include_tag '/assets/nospam.js'
```

The nospam.js file will already be compiled into the application.js file so there is no need to include it separately.

Also, you need to make sure your JQuery code executes after the html it refers to, so add a $(document).ready line like this:

**/app/assets/javascripts/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my-email').html(function(){
    var e = "me";
    (etc...)
```

Comment: I tried this thanks but in the Javascript console I can still see a 404 error for jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js, both of which are in /app/assets/javascripts/

Comment: Did you move the application.js to /apps/javascripts/application.js as someone else suggested and I forgot to mention above?

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

The asset pipeline compiles the `app/assets` directory to the `public` directory.

Since your `application.js` manifest is in the `public/javascripts` directory, the asset pipeline is not considering it (asset pipeline doesn't compile assets in the public directory, it's where it puts compiled assets). So move it to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.

All you need in your layout is:

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

Make sure `nospam.js` is located at `app/assets/javascripts/nospam.js`.

```
app/
  assets/
    javascripts/
      application.js
      nospam.js
```

Your manifest looks right to me. Just looks like files aren't in the right place.